# How do I find "php.ini" file

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to find a file which "php.ini" on magento because I want to take a extension which "Japanese Core Localize Extension".They say that I should rewrite mbstring on php-extension for using it.

It would be great if someone tell me how to find or create.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about `php.ini` file and has no relation with Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `php.ini` file is the default configuration file for running applications that require PHP. It is used to control variables such as upload sizes, file timeouts, and resource limits.

Magento is a PHP Based application. So what you are asking is not at all related to Magento.

In order to see you PHP configuration, you can create a `info.php` file and put below content in it :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This will show all php configurations available. `php.ini` file location is vary from system to system. Please do a search in google, you will get more details.

Comment: Thank you so much,it was helpful.
I was able to find it finally,and I did rewrite mbstring on server.

Comment: @Shota if this answer helped you to resolve your issue, then feel free to accept it.